# Show messages in console from windows service

Tags: c++, windows, service, console

When i double click on my server exe it runs as a console application and i can see the logs in console.
I have made a windows service using the code given at http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948 
Using this the server runs in background but i cant see the console. Can anyone tell me how can i send messages to the console from a service??

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it! I print my logs from my service to a pipe handle and i just wrote a simple pipe client which reads the file and displays it in the console. 
If anyone needs the code then ill post it here

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the code somewhere, as it will be useful to many people struggling with services.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Windows Vista the services are executed in a different session so most communications will not work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463353.aspx

Microsoft have some ways to communicate with services as described here (only first paragraph).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Hi, i want the server logs to be continuously updated in the window so message box wont work. Anyway through which i can directly stream the logs being updated on real time basis??

Comment: If you use log4net you can write your one adapter and do the transport level by yourself (I did a UDP log4net adapter)