# .NET Windows Services (WTSSendMessage) : Displays message on XP but not Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows

I have a issue when display a message using .NET window service on Windows 7.It worked properly on Windows XP.I know that it doesn't work on Windows 7 as explained in Microsoft site and a few forums including Stackoverflow.I have followed the following example(using WTSSendMessage) from Pinvoke.NET as mentioned in the Stackoverflow.But it didn't work either.that example worked on Windows XP properly.Can some one please help me as this is a really big issue needed to be fixed ASAP since we already migrated to Windows7.

**Signature:**

```
[DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool WTSSendMessage(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int SessionId,
            String pTitle,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int TitleLength,
            String pMessage,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int MessageLength,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Style,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Timeout,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pResponse,
            bool bWait);
```

**Variable declaration:**

```
public static IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;
public static int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;
```

**Code:**

```
  bool result = false;
    String title = "Hello";
    int tlen = title.Length;
    String msg = "Terminal Service!";
    int mlen = msg.Length;
    int resp = 0;
    result = WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, WTS_CURRENT_SESSION, title, tlen, 
    msg, mlen, 0, 0, out resp, false);
    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    System.Console.WriteLine("result:{0}, errorCode:{1}, response:{2}", result, err, resp);
```

Answer (score 5):

`WTS_CURRENT_SESSION` for a service on Windows 7 or later will equate to session 0, which isn't allowed user interaction.  You'll have to enumerate all the active sessions and send a message to each (which should just be one, unless the computer is running terminal services).  Something like the following:

**signatures:**

```
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int WTSEnumerateSessions(
                    System.IntPtr hServer,
                    int Reserved,
                    int Version,
                    ref System.IntPtr ppSessionInfo,
                    ref int pCount);

    public enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit
    }
```

**helper function:**

```
public static List<Int32> GetActiveSessions(System.IntPtr server)
{
    List<Int32> ret = new List<int>();
    IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;

    Int32 count = 0;
    Int32 retval = WTSEnumerateSessions(server, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref count);
    Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));

    Int64 current = (int)ppSessionInfo;

    if (retval != 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure((System.IntPtr)current, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            current += dataSize;

            if (si.State == WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive)
                ret.Add(si.SessionID);
        }

        WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

**in your code:**

```
    List<Int32> sessions = GetActiveSessions(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE);
    if (sessions.Count < 1)
    {
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        _SUDSEventLog.WriteEntry("No active sessions found: errorCode:", err);
    }
    else
    {
        bool result = false;
        String title = "Hello";
        int tlen = title.Length;
        String msg = "Terminal Service!";
        int mlen = msg.Length;
        int resp = 0;
        result = WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, sessions[0], title, tlen,
        msg, mlen, 0, 0, out resp, false);
        int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        System.Console.WriteLine("result:{0}, errorCode:{1}, response:{2}", result, err, resp);
    }
```

Comment: Its a good start but incomplete.  WTS_SESSION_INFO undefined and WTSFreeMemory undefined.  Probably avail at PInvoke but would be nice to have it all wrapped up neatly in a static class.

Comment: @user922020:WTSFreeMemory: [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr memory); and WTS_SESSION_INFO: [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
      public readonly int SessionID;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] private readonly string pWinStationName;
      public readonly WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

Comment: There is a `WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId` API.

Answer (score 3):

**YES it can be done!**

I know this is a little late, and this suggestion *appears* a bit dreadful it actually isn't:  you can ensure that the **FIRST** currently logged in user is messaged from a service simply by changing the line

```
 public static int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = -1;
```

to

```
 public static int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = 1;
```

this is because since `Vista` (EG: `2008`, `Vista`, `2008 R2`, `Win7`, `Win 2012`, `Win 8`, `Win 2016`, `Win Ten` etc) the ID is simply the **first logged** in user is always 1, the next 2 etc.

Similarly (.. and, therefore) you can ensure the **LAST** logged in user by doing the reverse, going DOWN the numbers I know it's naff but you simply loop ints down until you get a non error. You need to go down as the `WTSSendMessage` calls await a result procedurally (i.e. lock/wait the current thread)

Therefore: a solution whereby you message **ALL** logged in users (by setting the `timeout` to `zero`) and dispatching to a *guesswork of numbers* in parallel, via all different threads, and simply ignoring the dead threads.

I use a NuGet package to convert my *`c#`console* code to *`c#`service* via TopShelf [following this tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-windows-service-in-net-with-topshelf/) and using the `Thread[STAThread]` to make sure this works. It will always call the LAST logged in user which in Windows Ten is only ever one person.

```
class Service
{
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WTSSendMessage(
            IntPtr hServer,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)] int SessionId,
            String pTitle,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int TitleLength,
            String pMessage,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int MessageLength,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Style,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] int Timeout,
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] out int pResponse,
            bool bWait);
    public static IntPtr WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE = IntPtr.Zero;
    public static int WTS_CURRENT_SESSION = 1;
    public void Start()
    {
        for (int user_session = 10; user_session>0; user_session--)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(() => {
                try
                {                        
                    bool result = false;
                    String title = "Alert";
                    int tlen = title.Length;
                    String msg = "hi";
                    int mlen = msg.Length;
                    int resp = 7;
                    result = WTSSendMessage(WTS_CURRENT_SERVER_HANDLE, user_session, title, tlen, msg, mlen, 4, 0, out resp, true);
                    int err = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                    if (err == 0)
                    {
                        if (result) //user responded to box
                        {
                            if (resp == 7) //user clicked no
                            {

                            }
                            else if (resp == 6) //user clicked yes
                            {

                            }
                            Debug.WriteLine("user_session:" + user_session + " err:" + err + " resp:" + resp);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("no such thread exists", ex);
                }
                //Application App = new Application();
                //App.Run(new MessageForm());
            });
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
        }

    }
    public void Stop()
    {
        // write code here that runs when the Windows Service stops.  
    }
}
```

in case you're wondering this does work and the above code is all you need if you're following the boiler plate `TopShelf` examples

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this maybe part of Windows Messenger that is not present in Windows 7.

This [link](http://techsupt.winbatch.com/webcgi/webbatch.exe?techsupt/tsleft.web%20WIL~Extenders/Terminal~Server%20wtsSendMessage~and~Win7.txt) shows why (RPC disabled by default)

and possible solution:

> By default remote RPC is disabled on Windows 7. It can be enabled by setting the 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Terminal Server' value 'AllowRemoteRPC' to 1. However, this will only get you another error - 0x721 - which I am guessing is caused by Windows 7 not allowing 'nul' user access. There are several possible ways around this problem but I haven't tried any of them. One approach would be to add credentials from remote machines to the credential cache on the sending machine but I don't know how practical that is. There may be a way to allow 'nul' user access but that is probably not a good idea either.

And this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg465093): Shows a long worked example on doing this on what looks like Windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried this.But didn't work.this window service is running in a PC and not in a Terminal Server.Please come up with another solution if you have any.Cheers.

Comment: See this QA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527112/show-messages-in-console-from-windows-service

Answer (score 1):

You can show a non-blocking Message Box from your Windows Service to the User. For this, firstly, start a Service named "Interactive Service Detection" from "services.msc". Then initiate a Thread from your Windows Service. In the thread method use "MessageBox.Show()" method to display your Message box to user. Instead of manually starting "Interactive Service Detection" service you can start it c# program.